# Adding parameter to application root URL in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to find a way to add parameter to script tag, which has to start with application root. What's the correct syntax for scenario below (not rendering in this form):

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server" src="~/Scripts/utilities.js?v=<%$ MYAPP.Common.MainSettings.ApplicationVersion %>"></script>
```

I'd like to keep this code on aspx and not move it to code-behind class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start the path with **/** instead of **~/**

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server" src="/Scripts/utilities.js?v=<%$ MYAPP.Common.MainSettings.ApplicationVersion %>"></script>
```

You can also use ResolveUrl

```
<script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/utilities.js?v=" + MYAPP.Common.MainSettings.ApplicationVersion) %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/utilities.js?v=" + MYAPP.Common.MainSettings.ApplicationVersion) %>"></script> ` did the trick for me. `/` seems to cause trouble with virtual directory.